# Улучшить, ускорить часть кода

Tags: c#

Использую `HtmlAgilityPack`

И вот у меня в методе с полтора десятка таких блоков для разбора `html`, а как можно было бы улучшить ?

`odin`, `dva` - тут использую для примера. В оригинале более осмысленные названия.

```
        string odin = string.Empty;
        HtmlNode htmlNodeOdin = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(Xpath.itemOdin);
        if (htmlNodeOdin != null)
        {
            odin = htmlNodeOdin.InnerText;
            //.........
        }

        string dva = string.Empty;
        HtmlNode htmlNodeDva = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(Xpath.itemDva);
        if (htmlNodeDva != null)
        {
            dva = htmlNodeDva.InnerText;
            //.........
        }
```

**UPD**

Уточнение у @tym32167 после комментария.
@tym32167 - правильно ли я понимаю, что я должен сделать полтора десятка повторений метода ? и лучше ничего не придумать ?

```
    string odin = MyMethod(htmlDocument,Xpath.itemOdin);

    string dva = MyMethod(htmlDocument,Xpath.itemDva);
```

Метод:

```
    private string MyMethod(HtmlDocument htmlDocument, string xpath) 
    {
        HtmlNode htmlNode = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
        if (htmlNode != null)
        {
            return htmlNode.InnerText;
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ну напишите метод, который принимает документ и xpath, и возвращает innerText или пустую строку.

Comment: @tym32167 обновил для уточнения

Comment: Я не знаю сколько раз и как вам надо вызывать методы. Вы показали какой то код - я подсказал как улучшить конкретно этот код. Что там в остальных частях вашего кода мне не ведомо, потому это я комментировать не могу.

Comment: @tym32167  да, я имел ввиду касательно эту часть кода, понял, спасибо!

Comment: `лучше ничего не придумать?` - зависит от входных данных (которые вы нам не показываете). Я уверен, что в HTML есть один объект, внутри которого находятся нужные ноды. а значит их можно взять как массив и дальше проходиться циклом, не дублируя код.